# Android Studio hides files in native source folder subdirectories

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I want to use the android ndk in my existing java android library.
I have set up everything, compiling and running works. (Unit tests that use jni complete successfully)
This is how my file structure looks like:

[image: File structure (Project view)]

When I switch from "Project" to "Android" view in the project explorer it looks like this (as expected):

[image: Android View]

I want to move test.cpp, test.h and test_jni.cpp to a subdirectory to organize like this:

[image: File structure with subdir (Project view)]

But as soon as i make that change and switch to "Android" view again, the files are not displayed anymore:

[image: Android View (missing files)]

When I adjust the CMakeLists to look for those files in the subdirectory, everything still works but the files are still hidden. Why doesn't android studio display those files? What do I have to do to make it work? It would be very messy to put every h/cpp file into the root folder.

Comment: I think AS tries to organize C++ sources/headers by the targets that use them. If you were to add the sources/headers of your "testfiles" directory to a library/executable/etc, I think they should be grouped as such. tbh, I'm not much a fan of the layout here either, and usually just use the project view. It's looking likely that AS will stop trying to do this sort of organization in an upcoming release and will just show the directory structure instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing indexes (go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart) or restarting AndroidStudio manually. If it doesn't help, just fill in a bug report, and pray for it being fixed ;)